# How to retrieve all objects by foreigh key MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am new in DB, so I am not even sure that it is possible. I have two tables `class` and `students`

```
CREATE TABLE `class` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_class_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_students_class` (`ref_class_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_students_class` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_class_id`) REFERENCES `testdata`.`class` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;
```

then insert

```
INSERT INTO `testdata`.`class` (`name`) VALUES ('foo');
INSERT INTO `testdata`.`students` (`ref_class_id`, `name`) VALUES ('2', 'student1');
INSERT INTO `testdata`.`students` (`ref_class_id`, `name`) VALUES ('2', 'student2');
```

So, for now, I have 2 students that associated with one class. Then in my C# code I need somehow to retrieve this data from the DB in order to do it I created the procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `retrieve_class_by_id`(
    IN `class_id` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM class WHERE id=class_id;
END
```

But I here I don't know how to go further... Actually, I can from the code retrieve the class object and then get all the students from the table, but I wonder if it is possible to make it just within one procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the two tables:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.name, s.id, s.name
FROM class AS c
    INNER JOIN students AS s ON (s.ref_class_id = c.id)
WHERE c.id = class_id;
```

Use a `LEFT JOIN` if you eventually need also classes without students :)